# How can Python get access to Windows IAudioMeterInformation interface?

Tags: python, winapi

[IAudioMeterInformation interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368227(v=vs.85).aspx)  I searched Python questions on win32, but did not find any useful things.

Any advice will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: You can first see if there's already a Python package for the Windows Core Audio API. If not, you can see if there's a Python package for dealing with COM interfaces like IAudioMeterInformation and use that. Otherwise, I wouldn't know; you would need to ask a Python expert. As for how to actually use that interface, there's an example linked on the MSDN page you linked.

Comment: @andlabs Thanks, but there is no direct package I can find. I tried win32com and packages alike.

Comment: I don't know how to use it but surely there must be a way to import the various interfaces, IIDs, CLSIDs, and constants you need into win32com...

Answer (score -1):

I think, you can make it with "[pyWinCoreAudio](https://github.com/kdschlosser/pyWinCoreAudio)" (haven't tested yet, but it have "IAudioMeterInformation" and "AudioPeakMeter" in source code!)